# How to combine two SharePoint columns into one datatable column?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a datatable that I want to show the information from my SharePoint List. The table has three headers: Name, Department and Address. The Address column should combine two SharePoint columns(Address Line 1 and Address Line 2) from the same list and display in that column.

How do I combine the two columns into one datatable column? The Address Line 2 should also start on the next line after Address Line 1.

This is my current code for the datatable.

```
function mySuccHandler(data) {
           
        console.log(data);
        
        $('#registration_table').DataTable({
                "pageLength": 20,
                "aaSorting": [],
                "aLengthMenu": [[20, 50, 75, -1], [20, 50, 75, "All"]],
                "iDisplayLength": 20,
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "aaData": data.d.results,               
                "columnDefs": [
                   {
                       "targets": '_all',
                       "className": 'dt-left'
                   }
                ],
                "order": [[4,"asc"]],
                "aoColumns": [               
                
                {
                    "mData": "FullName"
                },
                {
                    "mData": "Dept"
                },

                {
                    "mData": "AddressLine1"
                                     
                },
                {
                    "mData": "AddressLine2"                                    
                }

                ]
                
            }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `aoColumns` as given below:

```
"aoColumns": [                          
    {
        "mData": "FullName"
    },
    {
        "mData": "Dept"
    },
    {
        "mData": getFullAddress                  
    }
]
```

Where `getFullAddress` is a function like:

```
function getFullAddress(data, type, dataToSet) {
    return data.AddressLine1 + "<br>" + data.AddressLine2;
}
```

You can also try other ways given in below reference thread.

**Reference**: [How to put multiple data in a datatable column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174560/how-to-put-multiple-data-in-a-datatable-column)

Comment: Thank you. It works, I also hid the extra column with bVisible.